# Basic C# How to use power to in for statement?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find sum of squares of numbers 1 to 100

What i'm trying to do

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double squareSum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            double iSquared = Math.Pow(i, 2);
            iSquared += squareSum;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(squareSum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

But I don't understand why "iSquared += squareSum" doesn't work, I used code break and saw that squareSum would remain 0.

I also tried

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                i*i+=squareSum;
            }
```

But it does not allow to use "i" twice in the same statement, is there a way write it this way?

And why squareSum remained 0 in the first statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't set squareSum variable ?

Comment: Why are you using real arithmetic for an integer calc?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Math.Pow` doesn't have any signatures that deals with `int`.

Comment: @Crono It is possible to compute the square of an integer without using real arithmetic. And preferable to do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are absolutely right, my bad. I was thinking *root* square in that silly brain of mine. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to swap them:

```
squareSum += iSquared;
```

First goes variable which will be incremented. See [+= Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

@Sergey's answer is the right one. Still, I thought you might find this useful:

```
var squareSum = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Sum(x => x * x);
Console.WriteLine(squareSum);
```

Of course you will want to ensure you have this on top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I haven't read about Enumerable.Range yet and was just looking for a way to use range of numbers, this gonna make stuff easier, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user3424243 You are welcome! I just edited my answer, now it computes integer values instead. Like David mentionned in comments above it will be more efficient than using real arithmetic. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of squares of the first 'N' consecutive natural numbers, you don't need Linq or for loops:

You just need the formula : `[n * (n + 1) * (2n + 1)] / 6`

In your case N = 100, so if you were to write the code in C# then:

```
int n = 100;
double result = (n * (n + 1) * ((2 * n) + 1)) / 6;
```

Comment: Care to explain yourself a little here?

Comment: The question said "I'm trying to find sum of squares of numbers 1 to 100". So this is the mathematical formula for finding the sum of squares of the first 'N' numbers. Here N = 100. If you are looking for the proof: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares

Comment: I just don't get why you're talking about the *first 'N' numbers*. What are the *firsts* and why only those?

Comment: By First 'N' numbers, i meant the first N consecutive Natural Numbers. So that means 1 to 100 in this case. Let me edit the answer to say "Natural".